# Convert dataframe index to string and substring?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Wondering whats the easiest way to split the following dataframes index into substrings and set the second piece as a column in the new dataframe.

```
Input:
          Ask    Bid   Last Open_Int Vol
245.0P  11.36  11.15  10.41       37  30
225.0C  10.31  10.23   10.3       52   5
224.5C  10.78  10.67     12       72  72
223.5C  11.68  11.56  12.68       89  59
244.5P  10.83  10.64   8.65      118  22
244.0P  10.34  10.15   9.93      137  10

Output:
          Ask    Bid   Last Open_Int Vol Type
245.0P  11.36  11.15  10.41       37  30 P
225.0C  10.31  10.23   10.3       52   5 C
224.5C  10.78  10.67     12       72  72 C
223.5C  11.68  11.56  12.68       89  59 C
244.5P  10.83  10.64   8.65      118  22 P
244.0P  10.34  10.15   9.93      137  10 P
```

Comment: How would you split exactly? I mean how would you split `245.0P`?

Comment: [245.0, P]. I dont know, substring, with the lengths of the string as the inputs to substring? And then df['Type'] = substring_out[1].

I can figure it out by iterating over the df, but theres the fancy lambda map stuff that can do this all in one line.  Wondering if anyone can show me that trick again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
df.assign(Type=df.index.str[-1])

          Ask    Bid   Last  Open_Int  Vol Type
245.0P  11.36  11.15  10.41        37   30    P
225.0C  10.31  10.23  10.30        52    5    C
224.5C  10.78  10.67  12.00        72   72    C
223.5C  11.68  11.56  12.68        89   59    C
244.5P  10.83  10.64   8.65       118   22    P
244.0P  10.34  10.15   9.93       137   10    P
```

​

Comment: You are so fast!

Comment: I get error. Probably because my dataframe is a json doc thats read from disk and making some encoding issue? AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values (i.e. inferred_type is 'string', 'unicode' or 'mixed')

Comment: @mobone use `df.assign(Type=df.index.astype(str).str[-1])`

Comment: Was my mistake. I had df and option_df, used the wrong dataframe. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For your very example this is the solution:

```
df['type'] = df.index.str[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your index is consistent, here's a straightforward approach to this problem
`df['Type'] = [str(_)[-1] for _ in df.index]`